# C# Socket SocketAsyncEventArgs when client is disconnected

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, socketasynceventargs

I have a problem, that I can not reproduce locally, but I can constantly reproduce on the server.

I have a TCP connection with the server and client. If I disconnect the client from the Wi-Fi TCP connection should be closed and the server should do some stuff upon disconnect. But I can not find any way from the server side to check if the connection is over. I implemented a heartbeat call, which runs each 5 seconds and sends a message to the client. I used `SocketAsyncEventArgs` for this. Looks something like this:

```
_socketAsyncEvent = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
_socketAsyncEvent.Completed += OnSendCompleted;

public void SendHeartbeat() {

  byte[] message = ...;
  _socketAsyncEvent.SetBuffer(message, 0, message.Length);

  if (!_connection.Socket.SendAsync(_socketAsyncEvent))
  {
     OnSendCompleted(this, _socketAsyncEvent);
  }
}

protected void OnSendCompleted(object? sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
   _socketAsyncEvent.SetBuffer(null, 0, 0);
}
```

I would assume, that it should throw `ObjectDisposedException`, as the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.sendasync?view=net-7.0#system-net-sockets-socket-sendasync(system-net-sockets-socketasynceventargs)) says when `The Socket has been closed.`. But it does not. Well, docs say, that: `Note that the successful completion of the SendAsync method does not indicate that the data was successfully delivered.`... So `SendAsync` is not a solution.

I also tried such code: `!(Socket.Poll(100, SelectMode.SelectRead) && Socket.Available == 0)`, but it also returns `true`, so I can not check with it too.

I also can not reproduce this behavior locally, because locally I can clearly see when receiving the answer `BytesTransferred` is 0, which means that the connection was closed. As the documentation says [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.bytestransferred?view=net-7.0#remarks). But it does not happen like this on the server.

The server is under Azure Load Balancer if this information changes something.

Any other thoughts, how can I understand from server-side, that the connection was closed?

Comment: You are using a Keep-Alive.  A Keep-Alive the client sends an empty TCP packet periodically so server doesn't close connection.  Normally you set the client Keep-Alive at 5 seconds.  Then at server you close connection if you do not see a packet from client every 10 seconds.  The Keep-Alive is usually implemented in the library an not user code.  The links you posted One is for Core 7 and the other for Net 4.8.  A lot of changes were made between Net 4.8 and Core 7.  Core was updated to allow Net library to run same on Windows and Linux.  A lot of Windows bugs were fixed.

Comment: Yes, sorry posted the wrong link. I'm using the lastest .net 7.

Comment: You should use the real Keep-Alive and not implement you own.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepoint.settcpkeepalive?view=net-7.0